# Can I build a consumer grade personal cloud?

Tags: hard-drive, cloud-storage, owncloud

(Not sure if this is the right site.)

I was considering buying a personal cloud, but all the cheap ones had iffy reviews so I thought, might as well build one myself.  My question is: will I be able to make something by myself that will be dependable?  (Assuming I buy dependable hard drives with a warranty, and an rpi running owncloud.). Can I assume that it's relatively as safe as buying a consumer grade personal cloud?

Comment: Well, uh, sure, of course you can. If someone else can build it, why shouldn't you (under the assumptions you already made your self)?

Comment: This seems to be asking for an opinion. Not sure if this is really appropriate for superuser. Maybe the Tom's Hardware forums instead? http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/ Or possibly the RPi forums? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: You may consider asking at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are tech-savvy enough to weigh the pros and cons of the various bits of hardware and software and are comfortable troubleshooting the kind of issues a self-built solution might have, building your own solution for home use is certainly a viable solution. As a bonus, with those skills, you should be able to pin down any relatively common hardware/software issues and fix or replace those yourself whereas on a consumer NAS, you'd have to replace (or RMA) the entire (or almost entire) system.

Given that you're asking the question to begin with, I suspect you may fall short of that level of expertise. Don't let that deter you. If you can afford it as an entertainment expense and don't care if you lose whatever you plan to store there, slapping together a Raspberry Pi, some hard drives, and some software is a good learning experience.

Aside: I think you might find the Raspberry Pi rather slow for large files such as video or audio.

Comment: Maybe the original Rapsberry PI...I am streaming a movie from a look/alike Lamobo R1 with an SSD hard disk as we speak.  http://linux-sunxi.org/Lamobo_R1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's pretty nice. I wasn't aware there was a GbE-capable RPi.

Comment: Have a look. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Pi and also, the poor cousin http://www.orangepi.org